# Why does matlab fft of a 2D function give different answers depending on order of dimensions?

Tags: matlab, fft

Matlab's fft2 is a wrapper around fftn, but the order of operation of 1D fft along dimensions differs.  To cut to the chase, the following gives a non-zero answer.  Why is this?  I can find no bug reports online.

```
foo=rand(64);
err=sum(sum(fft(fft(foo,[],2),[],1)-fft(fft(foo,[],1),[],2)))
```

Comment: It's normal behaviour, caused by numerical errors. The difference is very small. For example, `sin(pi)` gives `1.2246e.16` instead of `0`. See the linked Q&A for more details. Welcome to the site, and well done for including a minimal, verifiable example!

Comment: Good question! Indeed, order of operations matters when dealing with floating-point arithmetic, because the founding errors that happen in each step of the computation.